# Capture whole document, including dynamic textarea values

Tags: jquery, html

I have a report which prints out lines of records.
I can add and remove lines on this report and edit each column aswell.

Problem is when saving the document I use the bellow in a click event.
`var htmlText = "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>";`

This works fine on everything except the dynamically added rows.
The Row is there, but the text entered into the `textareas` are not.

Why would this info not be grabbed?

Comment: because browsers do not update the value in the textarea into the DOM, so what you are getting is just an empty textarea tag.

Comment: Does that only apply to `textarea`'s? So will a `input` work maybe?

Comment: I've added an answer that works for both `textarea` and `input`, you can remove the script for input if you don't need it, or you can add a script for `select` too if you need to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers do not update the value in the textarea back into the DOM whenever there is any input that is changed by the user, the same applies for input and select as well. So a workaround would be to apply the changes into the DOM yourself before saving your HTML file.

```js
$("#insert").on("click", function() {
  $("<textarea />").appendTo($("#htmlBody")).val("This is a dynamic textarea");
  $("<input type=\"text\" value=\"\" />").appendTo($("#htmlBody")).val("This is a dynamic input");
});

$("#save").on("click", function() {
  alert($("#htmlBody").html());
});

$("#saveTextarea").on("click", function() {
  $("textarea").each(function(index, item) { $(item).text($(item).val()); })
  $("input").each(function(index, item) { $(item).attr("value", $(item).val()); })
  alert($("#htmlBody").html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="htmlBody">
  <textarea>This is a textarea</textarea>
  <input type="text" value="This is an input" />
</div>
<button id="insert">Insert Textarea</button>
<button id="save">Save</button>
<button id="saveTextarea">Save With Textarea Value</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

simply:

```js
  $("#save").click(function(){
  
    $("textarea").text(function(){
     return $(this).val()
    })
    
    $("input").attr("value", function(){
     return $(this).val()
    })
    
    $("#result").text($("#form").html());
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="form">
  <textarea></textarea><br>
  <textarea></textarea><br>
  <input type="text"><br>
  <input type="text"><br>
</div>

<button id="save">Save</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```